# jquery.steps not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wizard

I've been trying to make this website with a steps form from jQuery.
I ran through multiple tutorials on how to use it, but it never works. It always shows me the whole content of the form without the "pagination" style steps.

I used an example from this [website](http://www.rafaelstaib.com/post/How-to-create-a-Form-Wizard-using-jQuery-Steps):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.steps.js"></script>
<link href="/Content/jquery.steps.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>


    <form id="wizard" action="#">
        <h1>Account</h1>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account Information</legend>

            <label for="userName">User name *</label>
            <input id="userName" name="userName" type="text" class="required">
            <label for="password">Password *</label>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="text" class="required">
            <label for="confirm">Confirm Password *</label>
            <input id="confirm" name="confirm" type="text" class="required">
            <p>(*) Mandatory</p>
        </fieldset>

        <h1>Profile</h1>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Profile Information</legend>

            <label for="name">First name *</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="required">
            <label for="surname">Last name *</label>
            <input id="surname" name="surname" type="text" class="required">
            <label for="email">Email *</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="required email">
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <input id="address" name="address" type="text">
            <label for="age">Age (The warning step will show up if age is less than 18) *</label>
            <input id="age" name="age" type="text" class="required number">
            <p>(*) Mandatory</p>
        </fieldset>

        <h1>Warning</h1>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>You are to young</legend>

            <p>Please go away ;-)</p>
        </fieldset>

        <h1>Finish</h1>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Terms and Conditions</legend>

            <input id="acceptTerms" name="acceptTerms" type="checkbox" class="required"> <label for="acceptTerms">I agree with the Terms and Conditions.</label>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

</body>

<script>
$("#wizard").steps({
    bodyTag: "fieldset"
});
</script>

</html>
```

It always looks like this:
[image]

Can someone help?
What am I doing wrong?

[EDIT1] I changed the code a bit. I added the div container with the wizard id around the form (updated the code and the image). So i get the container and the 'Next' and 'Prev' Buttons below. But still no functionality. Can someone give me the next breadcrump? [\EDIT1]

[EDIT2] After deleting the div container and changing the form id to "wizard" it looks like that. So the functionality is there but the contents of the form are gone. (Updated Code and Picture) [\EDIT2]

Comment: You should move your jQuery (`$("#wizard").steps({...`) to the end of the document or wrap it in a document.ready call.

Comment: Tried that, sadly it doesnt make a difference

Comment: Where is the actual "wizard" id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the bottom of the page you linked to, it's calling events

```
onStepChanging:
```

etc, you are not. the main documentation is [github jquery-steps docs](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki)

Comment: that is for a later step when validation is added. For now I dont want any validation. Just the pagination by steps

Comment: put id="wizard" on the form tag

Comment: Thanks Billy! that looks better.
Now I have the functionality, but the contents of the form are gone. I have all four pages and i can go through them with the buttons, but no content, the page is empty. What could be the problem?

Comment: Try  `var form = $("#wizard").show();`   above `$("#wizard").steps({
        bodyTag: "fieldset"` inside the script tag

Comment: I tried ´var form = $("#wizard").show();´, still no content however

Comment: Go to the docs page [here](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#advanced-form) and in the advanced form section click code - click javascript - and copy all the js, change #example-advanced-form to #wizard on the top line and change  headerTag: "h3", to  headerTag: "h1" on the 3rd line and see if that works

Comment: Got it working ? Don't forget to close the question.

Comment: Sorry, I wasnt in the office until now. Gimme a moment

Comment: The Basic Example is working if I copy the code from that site! Thanks for that in advance! But the advanced example still gives me the same problems like I mentioned above. No visible entities inside the form if I click through the tabs. It seems like the form.validate isnt working